# Use different css styles for colorbox on different pages?

Tags: jquery, css, colorbox

I am using Colorbox (the js library for popup windows) on a site.  On some pages, I need to use different looks for the colorbox and/or its parts (like the close box, use a different png file).

Since the js library generates the code for the popup div on the fly, what's the most efficient way to handle different "looks" for different pages on the site without duplicating any code?

Comment: Use a diffident css file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it generates HTML on the fly, it still use the same CSS as everything else. So just add on required page `<style>` tag with required css which will override default styles or prepare few css files, with css rules overriding default styles, which you will attach to your page when you need that.

Comment: Sorry, to be more accurate what I need to do is call two or more different colorboxes _on the same page_ with _different css parameters_.  Is there a way to assign an ID or a CLASS to the colorbox when calling it?  So I can have #yellowbox and #redbox"?

Comment: Hm. I would take a look at `onComplete` callback and add required style (`$('#colorbox').addClass("redbox")`) to some wrapper element (looks lik `#colorbox` is the one you need)

Comment: I just tried this but if fails (the colorbox never opens):
`$(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"200px", height:"500px", onOpen:myFunc});` and then
`function myFunc () {$('#cboxLoadedContent').addClass("redbox"));}`

Comment: Works, you're right needs onComplete.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could consider is having no CSS for the colorbox itself, but instead having the content of the pop up in its own page and call it via ajax. Have all the CSS for the particular pop up in its own page. I've used this method before. The only CSS you need in the colorbox file is the background colour/transparency/image.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about the Ajax loading method.  I have used the inline method so much in the past.  Good one.

Answer (score 0):

How about giving the `<body>` an `id` same as the file name such as `<body id="index">` and `<body id="about_us">` and than adding styles in the `colorbox.css` file such as

```
body#index wrapper gallery
{
 background-color: #foo;
}
```

I use [slimbox](http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox2) and do as above.

Comment: Thanks, but see my further elaboration, I need to have multiple boxes on one page with different attributes.  I've done what you suggest many times when there's only one on a page.  I might need, as FAngel suggests, to add the classes with a callback.

Answer (score 0):

I don't thing you will need a separate CSS file for that..

Lets say in first Page your colorbox is in

```
<div class="divA">

    // Color Box 1
</div>

<div class="divB">

    // Color BoX 1
</div>
```

You can add this class before the colorBox class's to get your work done.

```
.divA  colorbox-class
{
    // Your Style Color Box 1
}

.divB  colorbox-class
{
    // Your Style Color Box 2
}
```

Comment: But the colorbox is not in a div, is it?  I'm calling one on page load and others on click events.
    `<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $.colorbox({inline:true, href:"#intercept"});
  });
     </script>`

Comment: Ya that's true.. Just game you an example. Just open your firebug and check the parent in which the colorbox is wrapped

Comment: Thanks.  But having different boxes on the same page is the issue.  They are always greated with the same DOM structure, I need a good way to differentiate.

Comment: Just add a class to the parent container in which these are nested so that you can add your separate classes based on the container in which they are existant